# PHP `glob()` Multiple Prefixes

Tags: php

Ive seen several posts dealing with multiple suffixes but none with multiple prefixes. For some reason when I execute the code below it will only return those with the `comp` prefix.

```
$test = glob($dir."/{comp*, sb-*}", GLOB_BRACE);
var_dump($test);
```

same with this

```
$test = glob($dir."/{comp, sb-}*", GLOB_BRACE);
var_dump($test);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the space after the comma. It is trying to match a file that starts with a space, which is almost definitely not what you want. Instead do:

```
$test = glob($dir."/{comp*,sb-*}", GLOB_BRACE);
```